# INSERT changes auto_increment, but UPDATE not changes auto_increment?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table:

```
id int(11) auto_increment
name varchar(255)
```

auto_increment equals 1.
Insert row:

```
INSERT INTO `projects` ( `id` , `name`) VALUES ('350',  'project one');
```

Now `auto_increment` equals 351.
Update row:

```
UPDATE `projects` SET `id` = '351' WHERE `id` = 350 LIMIT 1 ;
```

`auto_increment` still equals 351. And we get error if try to insert a row:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '351' for key 1
```

How we can see `INSERT` changes auto_increment and `UPDATE` not changes `auto_increment`.

My goal is to update row and set `id` greater then `auto_increment`.

How to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of version ID on the project?

Comment: @BrianHoover, no. Project `id` connected with paper contract and sometimes I need to change id in the database to match paper contract id.

Comment: Make the updateable id a different field that is not the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you trying to set the auto increment value? Just let it do its job (clue - it is automatic).

So the best solution is when you insert a row let the auto increment chose the appropriate value for you and let that value be an invariant for that rows life time.

Otherwise just remove the `auto_increment` bit from the table definition and implement an appropriate system yourself.